# Artifactory docker registry docker image

Tags: redirect, nginx, docker, artifactory

I am playing around with the 4.13 version of artifactory using the pro-registry docker image

I created a virtual docker repo and a local docker repo as suggested in the doc and changed the nginx conf as follows

```
log into the running container 
sudo docker exec -i -t containerID# /bin/bash
vi /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf


ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/demo.pem;
ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/demo.key;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443  ssl;
        client_max_body_size 2048M;
        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/artifactory/;
                proxy_read_timeout 90;
        }
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log upstreamlog;
        location /basic_status {
                stub_status on;
                allow all;
                }
}

## Sub domain config for docker repository
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen 80 ;
  server_name my-docker-virtual.art.local art.local;

  if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = '') {
    set $http_x_forwarded_proto  $scheme;
  }
  ## Application specific logs
  access_log /var/log/nginx/docker-access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/docker-error.log;
  rewrite ^/(v1|v2)/(.*) /artifactory/api/docker/my-docker-virtual/$1/$2;
  client_max_body_size 0;
  chunked_transfer_encoding on;
  location /artifactory/ {
    proxy_read_timeout  900;
    proxy_pass_header   Server;
    proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /;
    proxy_pass         http://artifactory_lb/artifactory/
    proxy_set_header   X-Artifactory-Override-Base-Url $http_x_forwarded_proto://$host:$server_port/artifactory;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
    proxy_set_header    Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}
```

This works great I can do the following

```
docker login my-docker-virtual.art.local
user
pass
email

docker push my-docker-virtual.art.local/busybox

docker pull busybox
```

However when I change the nginx o the following

```
ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/demo.pem;
ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/demo.key;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443  ssl;
        client_max_body_size 2048M;
        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/artifactory/;
                proxy_read_timeout 90;
        }
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log upstreamlog;
        location /basic_status {
                stub_status on;
                allow all;
                }
}

## Sub domain config for docker repository
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen 80 ;
  server_name my-docker-virtual.art.local art.local;

  if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = '') {
    set $http_x_forwarded_proto  $scheme;
  }
  ## Application specific logs
  access_log /var/log/nginx/docker-access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/docker-error.log;
  rewrite ^/(v1|v2)/(.*) /artifactory/api/docker/wrong-docker-virtual/$1/$2;
  client_max_body_size 0;
  chunked_transfer_encoding on;
  location /artifactory/ {
    proxy_read_timeout  900;
    proxy_pass_header   Server;
    proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /;
    proxy_pass         http://localhost:8081/artifactory/
    proxy_set_header   X-Artifactory-Override-Base-Url $http_x_forwarded_proto://$host:$server_port/artifactory;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
    proxy_set_header    Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}
```

after this I reload the config

Everything still works which it should not, the redirect should fail. Shouldnt it?

Note that I am using the self signed cert that comes with the docker image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had to do a `service nginx restart` in order to see these changes reflected